Appropriateness of treating study site as a random effect in mixed-effects models when each site has a single predictor value
I have data from 12 study sites, each with a corresponding value for the area of built-up surface. At each site, I measured the body size of turtles and am interested in examining how body size varies along the gradient of built-up surface area. Since turtles within the same site are not independent, I am considering a mixed-effects model to account for this correlation. However, because each site has only one value for built-up surface area, I am unsure whether it is appropriate to treat study site as a random effect in this context.
Here is a sample plot showing the relationship between body mass and impervious surface cover (%). Since each site has a single value for impervious surface cover, I don't think it's appropriate to include random effects, because it wouldn't be able to estimate random effects for site because there is no within-site variation to model.


Building off of the previous answer, and your comment, your model might look like what we have below. Since you have not specified any turtle-level variables to include, the lowest level is very simple (just an intercept, and error term).
Measurement level
For turtle $i$ at site $j$
$$
BM_{ij} = \beta_{00} + r_{ij}
$$
Site level
$$
\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}Surface_{j} + u_{0j}
$$
Combined model
$$
BM_{ij} =\gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}Surface_{j} + u_{0j} + r_{ij}
$$
Here, we have a random effect of site ($u_{0j}$) and a fixed effect $\gamma_{01}Surface_{j}$ pertaining to the built-up area of that site. Then, $\gamma_{01}$ is the effect of built-up area on mean turtle body mass of a site. Remember, the random effect has to with correlations of your $y$ variable within a cluster (site), but not other characteristics of the site, so it's part of the design that each site will have only one built-up area measurement/value. What you don't want is all of the sites to have the same built-up area value.
From your plot, it looks like average BM decreases with increases in built-up area, and that obviously, all sites don't have the same value of the built-up variable value.

Rick, thank you so much for the clarification! I now have a better understanding of how the mixed effects model works.

Given that you have multiple turtle body size measurements within each site but only one value for built-up surface area per site, you can still use a mixed-effects model effectively.
You can treat the built-up surface area as a fixed effect. This allows you to directly model its impact on turtle body size. You will also have a grouping variable for each site treated as a random effect. This will account for the non-independence of turtle measurements within the same site. This way, you can model the correlation of measurements within sites.

Thank you for your response. Could you please clarify what the random effect (study site) is modeling in this case? Since there is no variability in built-up surface area within the sites, I'm not sure how a random effect for site would be meaningful. I've edited my question to better explain my concern.

George, thank you so much for your help! Your answer was helpful, and combined with the other answer below, I now fully understand what I’m doing.
